# Manually specify values for the filters and weights in a CNN architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[image: cnnImage]

How can I manually specify the values of the above "filters" and "weights and biases" using keras?

For example, a filter dim are 3 x 3 and equals `[[[0],[1],[0]],[[1],[1],[1]],[[0],[2 ],[1]]]`. Can also add them as a matrix of (3, 3, 1, 4).

For weights + biases:
Because (3 by 3), 4 filters will generate 2704 parameters, how can I supply a (2704, 3) matrix for the connections?

Comment: Using [`set_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights)? You can also pass `trainable=False` to the layer constructor if you don't want it to be changed during training.

Comment: @jdehesa can you kindly provide an answer with code to illustrate your thoughts ?

Comment: @jdehesa started a new question with code 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733984/accuracy-drops-when-setting-weights-in-keras-convnet